# PreparedStatement executeQuery closes ResultSet when called twice

Tags: java, oracle, jdbi

I'm working on a Java 8 project that has recently upgraded it's ojdbc (oracle) driver from ojdbc6:11.2.0.4 to ojdbc8:19.3.0.0. The upgrade has caused an issue with some of the existing code, that looks like below...

From the documentation I've read on ResultSet from Oracle, "A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed or re-executed", I'm assuming the **re-executed** part is whats actually closing 'resultSetOne', but its hard to say via debugging through the drivers decompiled source.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = PreparedStatements.getInstance().getStatement("someQuery");

// Assume this returns 2 results for this example
ResultSet resultSetOne = stmt.executeQuery();

while (resultSetOne.next()) {

    // This invocation closes resultSetOne
    ResultSet resultSetTwo = stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

**Resulting stacktrace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.ensureOpen(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:116)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:404)
```

I'm in a situation where I can't change the code. I'm looking for a potential vm argument that could get me past this issue with this specific driver, I've googled to no avail, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nothing you can do about that other than fix the code.  Sorry.

Comment: not sure it will help, but have you tried (running) with newer jre versions as well? in the past i had some strange issues when i updated mysql driver; my code was behaving incorrectly with java5, but correctly with java6 (probably due to a jdbc spec compatibility issue)

Answer (score 0):

1. Downgrade to the old jdbc driver
2. Build a custom driver jar which wraps the prepared statement with the semantics you need (this is gross, but can work)

If you cannot change any code, then switching back to the old driver and filling an issue with Oracle about the breaking change in behavior is your only real option.